How can I get all errors of a Hibernate schema validation?
In a Spring Boot 3.x application I can validate the JPA entities against the schema using this property: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate.
However, its main drawback is that the application logs one the first validation error during startup. That is, if there are multiple validation errors, I must repeat the fixing again and again.
Can I configure Hibernate in such a way that all schema validation errors are shown? Or maybe by writing a custom schema validator?
